# Modify and remove CSS class property using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to remove the property `min-width` from the class `ui-widget-content` and trying to modify the property from `width: auto !important;`  to `width: 250px;` for class `ui-dialog`.

Please note that these 2 changes should only be applied to the parent of `childDiv` and the implementation of the classes `ui-widget-content` and `ui-dialog` should be untouched elsewhere.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-dialog">
    <div id="childDiv">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

```css
.ui-widget-content {
    min-width: 360px;
    ...
}

.ui-dialog {
    width: auto !important;
    ...
}
```

**What I tried(With no success):-**

For removal:

```
$("#childDiv").parent('.ui-widget-content').removeAttr("min-width");
```

For modification:

```
$("#childDiv").parent('.ui-dialog').css({"width: 250px"});
```

Comment: min-width is not an attribute so `removeAttr()`won't affect that property. Set it to `0` instead like in your second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also met similiar situation as yours. Firstly, you cannot change css class itself using jQuery. Secondly, I will use new class to overwrite those parameter and easy to control. For your requirement in the example I will do like this:

Add new class:

```
.ui-widget-content-change {
      min-width:0px !important;
 }
.ui-dialog-change {
      width: 250px !important;
}
```

Then apply jquery

```
 $("#childDiv").parent().addClass('ui-widget-content-change');
 $("#childDiv").parent().addClass('ui-dialog-change');
```

When you don't want to use them, just remove those classes.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues. Firstly `min-width` is not an attribute, it's a CSS property, so calling `removeAttr()` will have no effect. To reset the property you need to use the `css()` method.

The second issue is with your use of `css()`. You can provide an object to it, however the syntax you're using in the object is invalid. You should provide a separate key and value, not a single string. Alternatively, you can provide the key/value of the property to set as separate arguments.

To correct the issue, try this:

```
let $childDiv = $("#childDiv")
$childDiv.parent('.ui-dialog').css('width', '250px');
$childDiv.parent('.ui-widget-content').css('min-width', 'auto');
```

More informaotion on the use of `css()` is available in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css)

Comment: Why setting `min-width` to `auto` when that property should be removed/disabled instead? I want to replicate the same behavior when we uncheck the CSS class property in the dev tools of browser.

Comment: It's because that's how CSS works. Every property is *always* has a value for an element, and that cannot be removed. In the case of `min-width` the default value is `auto`, which is why I reset it to that. You can find more out about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width): `Initial value: auto`

Comment: I want to use the value of `min-width` coming from an inherited CSS class, hence making it `auto` is not working correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the content of CSS-files using jQuery. With jQuery you can only modify the styles specified in the `styles`-Attribute of an element.

`$("#childDiv").parent('.ui-dialog').css('width', '250px');` adds `style="width: 250px"` to the parent `div` with the `ui-dialog` class. However this will not change the width, as you have marked width in the CSS-file as important.